# How are limits of integration changed?

Tags: integration

In a solution to a homework problem, I came across the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^t{\tau}x(\tau - t_o) d\tau$$

After making the substitution $v = \tau - t_o$, the integral then becomes:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{t-t_o} (v + t_o)x(v) dv$$

Can someone explain to me how the limits of integration change when making this substitution?

(This integral is actually part of a question asking to determine time invariance for a system with the above output less the $-t_o$)

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $\nu = \tau - t_0$, as $\tau\to -\infty$, so also $\nu\to -\infty$. This accounts for the lower limit. For the upper limit, at $\tau = t$, we have $\nu = \tau - t_0 = t-t_0$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{t}\tau x(\tau-t_0)d\tau$ really means
$$\int_{\tau = -\infty}^{\tau = t}\tau x(\tau-t_0)d\tau$$

If we substitute $v = \tau - t_0$. Then at $\tau = t$, $v = t-t_0$; and at $\tau = -\infty$, $v = -\infty$. Thus
$$\int_{v = -\infty}^{v = t-t_0}(v+t_0) x(v)dv$$